# How to run docker command in powershell script

Tags: docker, powershell

I need to execute the following docker command in powershell

```
docker run --rm --init -it --name aws-iot-greengrass --entrypoint /greengrass-entrypoint.sh -v c:/Users/%USERNAME%/Downloads/certs:/greengrass/certs -v c:/Users/%USERNAME%/Downloads/config:/greengrass/config -p 8883:8883 216483018798.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws-iot-greengrass:latest
```

But getting error => docker : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

So how to run docker command in powershell script

Comment: Make sure `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin` is in your system's `Path` environment variable. The path may be different depending where you have `DockerDesktop` installed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My docker installation file path => C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker\Desktop.exe. So how to re-write the above command?

Comment: The `docker` executable will be in a different location. I'd try adding the path `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin` to your `Path` environment variable. Go to **Control Panel** > **System Properties** > **Environment Variables** > `Path` and **Add** the path I gave.